# SSRS Report Subscription

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

Please help me if i could append time stamp to SSRS report subscription. Time stamp should be in YYYYMMDD format. 'ReportName @timestamp' is giving me timestamp in 2017_03_17. My Datasource is oracle.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: In Oracle you format the date like this: `TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD')`

Answer (score 0):

If this is for file names in subscriptions in SSRS, then no.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160334.aspx gives a list of all available variables for names (@ReportName & @ExecutionTime for emails, @TimeStamp for fileshare).